# Xcode benefits in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, objective-c, xcode, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

This question requires some knowledge of both `Xcode` and `Visual Studio`. I have a little more experience with `Xcode` and I have reaped some of its benefits.

First benefit is the **`#warning`** directive, I insert this in my `Xcode` projects when I am in the middle of debugging and want to come back and address an issue I noticed while debugging.

Another perk that I utilize is `ALog(@"..")` predefined macro. If anyone has seen this, it can be `DLog(@"..")` or whatever. It's function is to print the line number, the class, and the method from where it was called.

Is there anyway to use these two awesome concepts, **`#warning`** directive and `ALog(@"..")` (to print num line, class, and method from where called) in **Visual Studio**?

I am using both Visual Studio 2013 and 2012 Ultimate editions with the latest updates in Win8.1 and Win7. Also, I use visual studio for Visual C++ and Visual C#.

Thank you

Comment: and the question is what exactly?

Comment: Question is: How can I use a log statement, i.e. (cout << ...;) or System.Console.WriteLine("....."); or maybe even printf("..."); for VCPP and VCS to be able to log a custom message and have the time, line number, the method name from which I logged. (If any of this is possible in VS)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Xcode, but maybe this is what you're looking for?

There's a [warning directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963th5x3.aspx)

You cannot define macro's, but breakpoints can display several kinds of information.

You can also define a conditional method and use caller info attributes:
[caller info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx)

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
void Log([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "", [CallerLineNumber] int line = 0)) {
    Debug.WriteLine(memberName);
    Debug.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Your link to #warning directive works perfect for Visual C#! Exactly what I was looking for, now if this is possible in Visual C++ it would be nice. Not sure where I would define your suggested conditional method though. In the class? Outside the class? Does it become static?

Comment: @MuratZazi You can apply the ConditionalAttribute only to methods that return void. They can be static or not. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx